# What does the eye symbol represent when entering Gmail password?

Tags: gmail

I recently noticed the appearance of an 'eye' symbol that appears as I am entering my Gmail password. It was not there before. What is this?

[image: Example of 'eye' symbol]

If not an eye, it looks like a dot with an arc, or semi-circle, over the top.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/490570/how-do-i-remove-the-eye-symbol-from-password-fields-in-windows-8

Comment: It got nothing to do with gmail, it's browser behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Click the eye symbol when typing in passwords and you can see what you are inputting.

If you click on the password eye, what you have typed will show up to enable you to check the typing of your password. The password will only show up while the mouse button is pressed - as soon as you release the button your typing will disappear.

Some security considerations when using the password eye:

- Be wary of anyone looking over your shoulder.
- Avoid using it if your computer is being accessed remotely (by for example a tech support person) - even if it’s a trustworthy company.
- Do not leave your computer unattended with the password box filled in (but not submitted).